# Source and npm sripts

Tags: bash, npm

I wrote the script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "build": ". ./envsetup.sh | ./build"
}
```

when in envsetup.sh script I set variables  and I want to share them in build script.

If I run it by `npm run build` I see KeyError the variable does not exist.

But if I run this script in console by 2 commands:

`. ./envsetup.sh`

`./build`

the script is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a pipe here. This should work though:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": ". ./envsetup.sh && ./build"
}
```